Reactive REST endpoint fails to return a Flux from the external library
I have an application (a connector) that is built with io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.6.5. This application has it's own api and returns Flux<Item> that 'items' are pushed to flux from websocket subscription as String, mapped to particular object and filtered.
This connector is a library used in another program that is a Rest interface for such subscription, therefore it returns the Flux:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BrokerApiImpl implements Broker {

    private final BrokerService brokerService;

    @GetMapping(value = "tickerized_orderbook/{trading}/{profit}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Tick> subscribeTickerizedOrerbook(@PathVariable("trading") String trading,
                                                  @PathVariable("profit") String profit) {
        return brokerService.subscribeTickerizedOrderbook(OrderBookTickSymbol.builder()
                        .currency(CommonCurrencyPair.of(trading, profit))
                        .build())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
}

That API is registered in Eureka Server.
Then there is a client for this server which uses WebClient to reach the foermentioned API and want's to subscribe to the retrieved Flux:
    @Bean
    public List<WebClient> createAllWebClientBrokers(EurekaClient eurekaClient) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();

        return eurekaClient
                .getApplication("broker")
                .getInstances().stream()
                .map(q -> WebClient
                        .builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://" + q.getIPAddr() + ":" + q.getPort() + "/tickerized_orderbook/{trading}/{profit}")
                        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                        .build()
                )
                .toList();
    }

it's a Bean definition from when application starts so I don't need to make a trigger during the development.
and then subscribe:
    @Bean
    public Flux<Tick> subscribeRemote(List<WebClient> webClients) {
        WebClient client = webClients.getFirst();

        Flux<Tick> tickFlux = client.get()
                .uri(q -> q.build("btc", "usdt"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Tick.class);

        tickFlux.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .subscribe(t ->
                System.out.println(t));

        return tickFlux;
    }

I can tell, the REST controller is correctly reached and it tries to return a Fluc from the forementioned library, but now it fails on the server side with:
21:38:43.288 [ERROR] o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler - [2cfa943a-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/tickerized_orderbook/btc/usdt"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-2
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:86)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.flatMap(Mono.java:3116)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:172)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:172)
    *__________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:259)
    *___________Mono.then ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:259)
    |_      Mono.doOnNext ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:260)
    |_ Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:261)
    |_ Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResultMono(DispatcherHandler.java:168)
    |_       Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResultMono(DispatcherHandler.java:172)
    *__________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleException(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:322)
    *__________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleException(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:322)
    *________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handle(DispatcherHandler.java:154)
    *__________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:106)
    |_     Mono.doOnError ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:84)
    |_ Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:85)
    |_     Mono.doOnError ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:84)
    *__________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler$CheckpointInsertingHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:106)
    |_         checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/tickerized_orderbook/btc/usdt" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
...

So the exception is being thrown from BlockingSingleSubscriber::blockingGet:
if (Schedulers.isInNonBlockingThread()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } 

Obviously, I want it to return the flux to the client which would subscribe to it and do what's needed.
As you can see the class that is fails in is BlockingSingleSubscriber and that puzzles me, because I don't want anything blocking. I don't know where it is comming from and why. It's endless stream of data that I want to return to the client.
I tried to subscribe to that Flux when server starts, and it works. It subscribes no problem and data are coming in. Only that is worth nothing when I can't return the stream from the controller. Also, I have tried to return simple Flux.fromIterable(...) from that controller and that works! Even when I return such 'fromIterable' Flux and try to subscribe to my data stream before it fails on the same exception. Can't make a sense of it why.
Can you try to advice what is going on and how to fix this?
EDIT: add more stacktrace
EDIT2: remove 'second subscribe section', so client side subscribe is:
        client.get()
                .uri(q -> q.build("btc", "usdt"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Tick.class)
                        .subscribe(t ->
                System.out.println(t));

but result is the same.
EDIT3:
I found out, when I declare a bean returning the stream and then I inject that Flux<Tick> into the controller and return it, it works:
    @Bean
    public Flux<Tick> trySubscribe(BaseBroker broker) {
        return OrderBookTickSymbol.builder()
                .currency(CommonCurrencyPair.of("btc", "usdt"))
                .build()
                .live(broker);
    }

I can subscribe to it only once, for second time it won't do anything, not even an error, but the first subscription client gets the data as expected. Not much but progress.
EDIT4: I did an example. it resembles my original project with structure, however behaves a bit different - still not correct. the 'sink' module is basically my library, that's where subscription logic is. The 'ctrl' module is what includes the library (sink) and exposes a REST controller. 'client' is what requests a stream from 'ctrl' using a WebClient. What it does, is when I send a request, the 'ctrl' module executes subscription logic, I can tell by uncommenting subscribe with log() in 'Service' and I can see the logs, but I can not achieve the WebClient to see that stream which it requests. That's what I need controller for, I don't know how to use is apparently and would appreciate a guidance; it's still not what happens with my original topic/exception, but may help clarify things.
Spring-Boot parent: 3.2.3
Spring-Cloud dependencies: 2023.0.2

Can you show the whole stacktrace? I think it should contain exact place where you have it. And btw, you should not have the second section for tickFlux in your subscribeRemote, it makes a subscription which it should not do.

I added more stacktrace and tried without that second subscribe section, but it's the same. you can see the place it fails: it's that condition that evaluated truthy, just why it's even in the blocking subscriber class when I'm not blocking anything, dont know..

Btw, by "remove" I mean removing it completely. You should NOT have a subscribe(..) in your code anywhere, unless there are very specific reasons. But it's likely unrelated, as it more likely just makes two requests of which one you ignore.

can you show your brokerService.subscribeTickerizedOrderbook?

not really, but what happens there, is I create sink as Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer() publish data to it, and return flux as with .asFlux(). edited question I found out something new to it

Your EDIT2 still contains a subscribe call. And I'm not sure that using a Sink is a right approach, it's easy to misuse it. Instead of a Sink try to collect the data in a reactive way

just to be clear on that subscribe call: that is why I am doing it for. on the client side, I want to subscribe to the stream (Flux) that server returns, that's what's that all about. maybe I'm misunderstanding you. to the other point, I'm no expert here; I just need to create subscribable sink, that I am able to push data from the websocket to it. is there another way to do it?

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.html this seems to be exactly what I need with https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.Many.html#asFlux-- to be returned from that controller. is there a reason why this should fail when returned directly and work when proxy-returned as spring-bean? don't think so

I understand it may be what you think you need a Sink, but it's like a adapter for a non-reactive approach. Because of that I think it's easy to make a mistake when trying to convert a non-reactive code to a reactive one. Though I understand it's not always possible to have everything reactive.

Subscribe is what Weblux does. I guess it's not explained well in the reference docs, but that the subscription is the final point of the flow, that's where you consume the data, the last step when it's available. And for a web-app you don't usually have it in your code, unless you want to throw it out. You just return a Flux/Mono to Spring, and it makes the subscription to it to move the data to the HTTP connection.

I created a PoC, linked in the question, I isolated the similar concept that I had originally, it's 3 module Maven project, can be run and actually subscribes to Bitfinex WS, but WebClient is not getting any data nor it throws the original exception that got this going

you have multiple subscribe calls in your code. there is absolutely no reason to have any of them, and each of them breaks the reactor. you use spring, so it's spring's responsibility to do the subscription, you should not have it in your code

the one in the Service is just to check out whether there are come data flowing. that will be gone when I have the data on the client side which still doesn't work

what is the result of tryEmitNext(..)?

So I figured where is that error coming from: it's really from calling .block() on the Mono. During the first call that uses the socket, I designed the factory method such that it is non blocking, but didn't wanted to do anything in parallel for now, so I just called .block() when socket is first created. Even through the Flux that is the call all about is not being blocked anywhere, for Reactor it is enough to detect 'some' .block() within the controller's logic and it throws IllegalStateException.
No wonder, the check is static, so it can not tell better (?).
This was my issue and this is how it is, somebody from the Reactor team could confirm if this is desired behavior or bug.
